# Create react app service worker nginx no cache configuration

Tags: facebook, nginx, service-worker, create-react-app

I am trying to set cache header for service worker through nginx in [create react app project](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), in the configuration, I tried

```
location /service-worker.js {
  add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
  proxy_cache_revalidate on;
  expires off;
  access_log off;
}
```

However when I load my page, sw registration fails with the message.

`A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
registerServiceWorker.js:71 Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

Can someone please suggest a way with nginx using create-react-app?

Comment: are you sending a get request to /service-worker.js? if so, is this file present in your public/assets directory

Comment: did you find the solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per your configuration `service-worker.js` must be in `/` root directory defined with `root` nginx directive.

Please check if the file is present there. If you are using express and express static and have placed the file in public/assets directory, it won't work. if for this file you want to to have different location. you can use `alias` directive.